# javax.xml.ws.AsyncHandler is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces

Tags: soap, jaxb, jax-ws, reactive

I am trying to implement a JAX-WS web service as asynchronous and Bridging to Project Reactor.
I have implemented the client side code as follows:

```
        Mono<IsAgentAuthorizedResponse> isAuthResponse = Mono.<IsAgentAuthorizedResponse>create(sink -> servicePortType.isAgentAuthorizedAsync(isAgentAuthorizedRequestBean, outputFuture -> {
            try {
                sink.success(outputFuture.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                sink.error(e);
            }
        }));
```

The SEI looks like below

```
@WebMethod(exclude = true)
@RequestWrapper(localName = "isAgentAuthorized", targetNamespace = "http://authapi.agentauth.rakuten.com", className = "com.demo.agentauth.authapi.IsAgentAuthorized")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "isAgentAuthorizedResponse", targetNamespace = "http://authapi.agentauth.demo.com", className = "com.demo.agentauth.authapi.IsAgentAuthorizedResponse")
public Future<?> isAgentAuthorizedAsync(
    @WebParam(name = "request", targetNamespace = "")
    IsAgentAuthorizedRequestBean request,
    @WebParam(name = "asyncHandler", targetNamespace = "")
    AsyncHandler<IsAgentAuthorizedResponse> asyncHandler);
```

I am getting the following error:

com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.db.DatabindingException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
javax.xml.ws.AsyncHandler is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at javax.xml.ws.AsyncHandler
        at public javax.xml.ws.AsyncHandler com.bjit.consume.async.esanew.way.jaxws.IsAgentAuthorizedAsync.asyncHandler
        at com.bjit.consume.async.esanew.way.jaxws.IsAgentAuthorizedAsync
java.util.concurrent.Future is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.util.concurrent.Future
        at public java.util.concurrent.Future com.bjit.consume.async.esanew.way.jaxws.IsAgentAuthorizedAsyncResponse._return
        at com.bjit.consume.async.esanew.way.jaxws.IsAgentAuthorizedAsyncResponse

Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions